# can't find package zmq, "package require zmq"

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, debian, deb

When I'm trying to run a file I received this error?

```
can't find package zmq while executing "package require zmq"
```

How can I install zmq in Ubuntu?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should install `zeromq`. See [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zeromq).

Answer (score 0):

For Debian based distros there is a nice ZMQ page which explains how to install it with apt-get:
http://zeromq.org/distro:debian